# gcc optimization causes unexpected return value

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

```
class C
{
   virtual const char* foo() const {return C::bar();};
   static const char* bar() {return "sdfsdf";};
};
```

As long both functions return a pointer they should return the same one - even if `bar` is inlined, because `foo` should return the result of `bar`.

But in release `foo` is "optimized" so a copy of "sdfsdf" is created and the functions are now returning different addresses. How do I get the expected value to be returned?

Comment: Which exact optimization levels are used? It might well be the compiler decides to stay in cache line for speed vs size, and uses a copy there.

Comment: I can't believe that "optimized" = using twice as much memory now.  That doesn't sound optimal to me.

Comment: @Shafic, I don't expect literals to have the same address, I expect foo to return the result of bar

Comment: Can't reproduce, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and as @πάνταῥεῖ asked the optimization levels and other flags as well as gcc version as system would be helpful.

Comment: Could not reproduce .https://ideone.com/qlJpad

Comment: Does this (only) happen if foo and bar are called from different translation units?

Comment: @rici no it is in the same one like foo() == C::bar()

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

It happens when C::bar is inlined in different compilation unit, which makes sense and doesn't brake the standard.

Here is the solution:

```
class C
{
   virtual const char* foo() const {return C::bar();};
   static const char* bar() {static const char* s = "sdfsdf"; return s;};
};
```

Answer (score -1):

"I don't expect literals to have the same address I expect foo to return the result of bar"

No where in your program is it defined that the result of bar is `const` thus you can't even guarantee that two calls to `C::bar()` will return the same pointer address.  C++ is free to do this if it decides it is an optimization.

And so calling `C::bar()` and calling `C::bar() via C::foo()` can return different pointers.  Defining `C::bar` to be a const function might fix this (and might not).

Comment: Bar cant be const function, it is static

Comment: `static` means one function per class (i.e. no implicit `this`).  `const` means the function depends only on the parameters passed to it and not any other state (i.e. no globals, or IO).

Comment: i have solved the problem by adding not inline attribute, but the behavior is weird

Comment: you can't have static functions declared as const. const function means you can call it on const instance

Comment: Oops, sorry, another gotcha between C and C++.  In C `const int func(...` describes a function which is const not a return value which is const ...

Comment: The `const` in `const int foo() {...}` is meaningless in both C and C++.

Comment: Not true in C: in C this defines the function as depending _only_ on the parameters passed to it, such that the compiler can perform CSE and call the function less than expected.

Comment: @dave: I suspect you're thinking about an old GCC extension which allowed you to use something like `typedef int foo_func(); extern const foo_func foo;` to declare that `foo` only depends on its arguments; see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html. It's much easier to declare it as an attribute `int foo() __attribute__((const))`, and the gcc 5.2 manual no longer documents the other syntax. In all versions I tested, `const int foo() {...}` triggers a warning similar to `warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]`